# network-on-chip verilog code

Tags: networking, verilog, synthesis, system-on-chip

I have written and simulated a Verilog code in ISE Project Navigator 2013. this is an RTL model that describes the network-on-chip routers, buffers and links.

1. which device is better for synthesis and implementation?
2. How can I get the static and dynamic power consumption, a packet transfer delay, area and the other factors that indicates network performance, using ISE Project Navigator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is very open ended so I will try to provide as general an answer as possible.

Now you have said that you have the code for a NOC Router in ISE. This would imply that you or the designer has a rough idea of the frequency at which the internal logic/system has to operate. The maximum clock tree frequency of your target device and would then be one of the key parameters that you need to check. If your design is running at around 150-200 MHz and is appropriately pipelined (small muxes, not more than 2-3 levels of logic between pipelining stages), then almost any of the currently available device families from both Xilinx and Altera should be suitable.

The next important consideration is of external connectivity. Does your design need high-speed serial connectivity with an external device. If that is true, then you would need to select a device that has high-speed SERDES IPs in-built. That would then limit your choice of devices.

Another factor to consider is interface to external SDRAM or RLDRAM. If your design needs to interface with such external devices, then you need to pick a device that has support either through a softcore or a Megafunction (Altera) or a hard IP block.

Finally you need to look at your logic utilization. You want to chose a device that is just big enough to satisfy your requirements, unless your design is part of a bigger project and there are modules that would be designed later and would sit alongside your NOC. You would have to make a rough guess of the number of LEs/LUTs that your design would need and pick a device 50% bigger than that. You can then run a trial synthesis run and check if your estimates are okay. If they are, and your device is less than 50% utilized, you could go in to a smaller device as need be.

There are also a few other considerations such as number of IOs, presence of a PLL/Clock manager that may affect your choice of device